# Correct variable reference to a file upload field in PHP

Tags: php, string

I am trying to successfully use the PHP `empty()` function. Currently my script references the input file field variable:

```
<input  class="fileUpload" name="flyer" type="file"  />
```

like this:

```
if (empty($_FILES['flyer']['name'])) {
//don't update the file 
}
else {
//update the file url
}
```

This currently updates the file URL to a value of `null` if it's empty. The problem could be something else but I think it's my variable reference. How can I correct this to get the `empty` function to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if it is a FILE type then you need to use the $_FILES[-name-]['error'] handler to check the quality of file, check http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Ignore the name value, what you want is

```
if ($_FILES['flyer']['error'] == 4) {
//// this file given was empty. 
}
```

Comment: `FILE['error']` that's more like `$_FILES['error']` - but more specifically as per the link to the "manual" - `$_FILES['userfile']['error']` ;-)

Comment: @Martin so with this this if the file field is empty the if statement won't run at all?

Comment: @Rhillz strictly speaking the `$_FILES` should only be processed if  `$_FILES['flyer']['error'] == 0` where zero is that no error was encountered and the file was uploaded ok, the name of the file is identified with the `$_FILES['flyer']['tmp_name']` field once uploaded, but before being saved.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from $_FILES['flyer']['error'] you can also check whether any file exists or not at the desired location.

```
if(!file_exists($_FILES['flyer']['tmp_name']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['flyer']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo 'No upload';
}
```

Check this [link](http://php.net/is_uploaded_file) for detailed information about is_uploaded_file()